# Site's Impressions, click and ranking were drop to 0 in one day, without any visible technical problem. What might be the reason?

Tags: seo, google, ranking, impressions

My site is about 6 months old. During that time its impressions and clicks increased. Over time the site gained momentum and the number of impressions and clicks has increased in the last two months.

Suddenly 3 weeks ago, on January 4th, the impressions dropped down to 0 (attached) and the site disappeared from Google's search Pages from my site that were ranked relatively high, disappeared from the search. The pages are still indexed and there are no security errors or other errors in Google Console.

My site robots.txt files are valid, with no security alerts or manual action detection.
I didn't find any broken pages or any other critical issues.

I can't figure out what might caused this problem.

Has anyone else experienced this recently or at all?
I already checked similar questions/answers

[Dropped impression 25 days after restructure](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54032/dropped-impression-25-days-after-restructure?rq=1),

[How to diagnose a search engine ranking drop?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16941/how-to-diagnose-a-search-engine-ranking-drop),

but it seems it was asked a long time ago and is less relevant.

Do you happen to know about the algorithm change Google did around Jan 4th?

I would love to hear suggestions or reasons why this might happen. Thanks

[image]

Comment: We use the community catch-all wiki for these types of questions since many factors could possibly be involved and we can't go through all of them with each question of this type. It appears there was an algorithm change around [January 4th](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-local-ranking-algorithm-update-jan4-36671.html) affecting _local_ SEO, but we don't know enough about your site to be able to provide a definitive answer (e.g., it's regarding local SEO).